# Cloning and filling tables dynamically

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am trying to generate and populate bootstrap tables from a json. 
The json object looks like this:
`[{"1":[{field1:data1,...},{...},...],"2":[{...},...]...}]`

The jQuery function generating the tables from the json looks like this:

```
function fill_table(){
        host = $.url('?host');     //gets parameter from url
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/cgi-bin/lalala/some.py",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {"target":"ports", "host":host},
          success: function(response) {
            var table = $("#porttablediv .bootstrap-table") //For cloning table
              $.each(response[0], function (key, value){    //Just generating tables
                html = "<h1>Module "+key+"</h1>";
                $("#porttablediv").append(html)
                var a = table.clone(true,true).appendTo("#porttablediv");
                a.find("table").attr("id", key)             //For later fill <-- PROBLEM?
              })
              $.each(response[0], function (key, value){    //filling tables
                $("#"+key).bootstrapTable('load',value)
              })
          },
        });
      }
```

So the tables are being generated correctly and have the exact same code structure as a the bootstrap-table library generated ones. **BUT!**
When I fill them, nothing happens, not an error, neither success, although the other ones do.

**EDIT 1:**

The bootstrap-table library converts this:

```
<table id="porttable" class="table table-bordered" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-columns="true"        data-show-export="true"  data-search="true" >
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" >Name</th>
          <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
          <th data-field="speed" data-sortable="true" >Speed</th>
          <th data-field="label" data-sortable="true" >Label</th>
          <th data-field="module" > Module</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

To this:

```
<div class="bootstrap-table" style="display: none;">
  <div class="fixed-table-toolbar">...</div>
  <div class="fixed-table-container" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="fixed-table-header" style="display: none;"><table></table></div>
    <div class="fixed-table-body"><div class="fixed-table-loading" style="top: 42px;">Por favor espere...</div>
      <table id="porttable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-export="true" data-search="true">
        ...
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-table-footer" style="display: none;">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
  var a = table.clone(true,true).appendTo("#porttablediv");
  a.find("table").attr("id", key)
```

This line `table.clone(true,true).appendTo("#porttablediv");` returns `table` and not `"#porttablediv"`. S0 the next line `a.find("table").attr("id", key)` should be changed to `a.attr("id", key)` as `a` is the `table`

---

**So the final code is**

```
 var a = table.clone(true,true).appendTo("#porttablediv");
 a.attr("id", key);
```

Or simply

```
var a = table.clone(true,true).appendTo("#porttablediv").attr("id", key);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.. Also, when you declare a table using bootstrap-table, the id is set in the tag table. I edit the original post to make that clear.

Comment: @SergiAregalldelaTorre can you add any jsfiddle to reproduce the issue? So that we can work this out better